# Partial view not rendering because TempData is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is part of my Index view:

```
@if (TempData["SucessAlert"] != null)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_SuccessAlert.cshtml");
}
```

Here is the partial view, _SuccessAlert.cshtml:

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    @TempData["SuccessAlert"]
    <a href="@TempData["SuccessAlertLink"]" class="alert-link">@TempData["SuccessAlertLinkText"]</a>
</div>
```

Here is part of my controller:

```
TempData["SuccessAlert"] = "Successfully created account code " + mergedCode + ".";
TempData["SuccessAlertLinkText"] = "Click here to view it.";
TempData["SuccessAlertLink"] = "/AccountCode/Details?Division=" + viewModel.Division
    + "&ProgramCode=" + viewModel.ProgramCode
    + "&ProjectCode=" + viewModel.ProjectCode
    + "&includeDisabled=False&page=1";

return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Everything worked fine until I added the `@if()` statement to the view. Apparently `TempData["SuccessAlert"]` is always null when this `@if` statement is checked. Actually, if I change the `@if()` statement to `@if(true)`, it still works, so `TempData` has the correct values inside the partial view, even though it's null in view itself.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? (I'm using MVC5, if that matters.)

Comment: There's a typo (missing "c") in `TempData["SuccessAlert"]` in the if clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bah! I just realized I misspelled "Success" as "Sucess" (one "C") in the @if() statement. I'm going to leave this here to document the fact that I am an idiot, as well as on the off chance that someone else will find this lesson useful -- double-check the spelling of TempData and ViewBag keys.